# Several Custom UITableViewCells in one NIB - how to refer to in code?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview

I'm creating custom UITableViewCells using the approach outlined on this page:

http://icodeblog.com/2009/05/24/custom-uitableviewcell-using-interface-builder/

So my cellForRowAtIndexPath code looks a bit like this:

```
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CustomCell";
TableCellWithLogo *cell = (TableCellWithLogo *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    NSArray *nibObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"TableCells" owner:nil options:nil];
    for (id currentObject in nibObjects)
    {   
        if ([currentObject isKindOfClass:[TableCellWithLogo class]] )
        {
            cell = (TableCellWithLogo *)currentObject;
        }
    }
}
cell.customTextLabel.text = [tableArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
return cell;
```

Now, the table I'm creating looks like a stylized version of the grouped tableview style, with drop-shadows etc. So it needs four possible styles of table (top, center, bottom .. and top+bottom for when only a single cell is showing).

I'm having trouble working out how to put all of these table cells into one nib, and then refer to them. At the moment I have a nib with a UITableViewCell whose class is 'TableCellWithLogo'. This class has all the relevant IBOutlets. If I put several UITableViewCells in the nib (all of TableCellWithLogo class), how would I be able to differentiate between them in code? You can see in the example above I'm finding out the class:

`if ([currentObject isKindOfClass:[TableCellWithLogo class]] )`

..but all the classes would be the same, so I'm not sure how to differentiate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create one empty nib and add table view cells to it. Also, for each of them create a corresponding class and assign the relevant class for each of them (see the screenshot). [image]

Then, in the cellForRowAtIndexPath you'll need to create different cells based on indexPath.row

Comment: Thanks. I think you've misunderstood my question, or I didn't make myself clear enough. All of the cells have the same IBOutlets, so I wanted them to use the same class. I've solved the problem by changing the tag in IB for each Cell and then refering to them thus: `if ([(TableCellWithLogo *)currentObject tag] == 1) cell = (TableCellWithLogo *)currentObject;` etc

Comment: Oh, sorry about that. Glad to hear you've found a way.